# Can I configure an aggregate "home page" with questions from different sub stacks which meet my tags there?

Tags: feature-request, tags, personalization

I have been a Stack Overflow member for a couple of years but I'm also interested in a variety of non-computer related topics. I often check the "Hot Questions" list. But those questions, while interesting both in themselves and as an indication of what moves the community, are not custom-tailored to my interests.

Is there a way to configure a book-markable page that assembles questions from various Stack Exchange Sites which match my respective tags there, similar to my configured Stack Overflow start page but aggregated from all stacks?

Comment: @Shadow Funny, that question didn't show up in the "possible duplicates". I actually tried the suggested solution (go to the Stack Exchange site and try to prepare a filter) but didn't seem to be able to add more than one tag, and also couldn't imagine that this interface is meant for this job.

Comment: Actually, it's even better: in [this page](https://stackexchange.com/filters) you should see "Favorite Tags" under "Select Filter" to the right. This will show exactly what you're after: list of questions tagged with one of your favorite tags, over the whole network. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use stackexchange filter page for this

https://stackexchange.com/filters/

You can filter and add rule from multiple sites and multiple tags.

Comment: It was only able to enter a single tag; generally, the interface seems not designed for the task described. It fundamentally doesn't seem practical to choose from thousands of unrelated tags.

Comment: you can add multiple tag each time like first add one tag then choose other tag and then add.